# sync multiple tables at once in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize now.
And I want to ask how can I sync multiple tables at once in Sequelize.
My current code is like below:

```
    Account.sync().then(() => {
      console.log('account created');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error');
    });

    Quiz.sync().then(() => {
      console.log('quiz created!');
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error');
    });
```

I've tried things like Quiz.sync().Account.sync() but it didn't worked on my dev environment. (webpack plus babel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sequelize.sync()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#syncoptions-promise) which synchronizes all database tables.